# Downcast / subclass UIViewController for mock in unit test

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I have a unit test and I want to create a subclass version of an `UIViewController`, for example `Test1ViewController`. Specifically, I want to override the `present` method for this class.

I have a view controller extension which instantiates a view controller, depending on its class name.

```
public class func instanceFromStoryboard<T>(storyboard: Storyboard) -> T {
    return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: T.self)) as! T
}
```

And a Storyboard class.

```
public enum Storyboard: String {
    case main = "Main"
}
```

In my unit test, I created a subclass from `Test1ViewController`.

```
class Test2ViewController: Test1ViewController {
    var presented: Bool = false
    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        presented = true
    }
}
```

How can I use my extension method to retrieve the view controller from the storyboard, and then downcast / subclass to `Test2ViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

Because objects in storyboards are actually encoded objects, they can't be decoded and cast to anything else. This is a drawback of using storyboards. What you put in a storyboard is what you get out.

If you can, use a XIB-based view controller instead of a storyboard-based one. With XIBs (and with programmatic view controllers), tests can instantiate subclasses.

If not, then you'll need to introduce a back door to your view controller. This would be unfortunate, as it means mixing test code into your production code.

Comment: This is a very good explanation of why this is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

[@Jon Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246895/jon-reid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585305/809944) nicely sums up the limitation of using Storyboards.

If your end goal is verifying whether the `UIViewController` under test has presented something, have you considered inspecting the `presentedViewController` property?

```
// Create an asynchronous expectation to verify the view controller has presented
// something.
_ = expectation(
  for: NSPredicate(
    block: { input, _ -> Bool in
      guard let viewController = input as? UIViewController else { return false }
        // If you care about the type of the presented view controller you could
        // use `is` here to verify it
        return viewController.presentedViewController != nil
      }
    ),
    evaluatedWith: viewControllerUnderTest,
    handler: .none
)

viewControllerUnderTest.doSomething()

waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil)
```

Another approach, which takes more work but also pays off over time by making your view controllers easier to move around in the navigation flow, would be to use a delegate for all the presentations.

In the test then you wouldn't check whether something has been presented, but only if the navigation delegate method to present something has been called, using a [Spy test double](https://www.mokacoding.com/blog/swift-test-doubles/). *Happy to provide more details if you're curious about this approach.*

Answer (score 0):

[@mokagio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809944/mokagio)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55603180/498796) should work. I prefer another approach.

```
func test_presentationOfViewController() {
  // Arrange
  let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
  window.rootViewController = sut
  window.makeKeyAndVisible()

  // Act
  sut.presentNext()

  // Assert
  XCTAssertTrue(sut.presentedViewController is DetailViewController)
}
```